# Why does a majority of White Evangelicals not support a pathway to citizenship for undocumented migrants?

Tags: united-states, immigration, religion

> In a survey released on Thursday, PRRI found that, while overall
> support for a pathway to citizenship has remained virtually unchanged
> between 2013 and 2021 (63% to 62%), some faith groups have undergone
> notable shifts.
>
> Support among white Catholics dropped from 62 percent to 54 percent,
> for example, and those who claim a non-Christian religion dipped from
> 68 percent to 55 percent.
>
> The most notable shift occurred among white evangelicals: In 2013,
> most of them (56%) backed a pathway to citizenship in 2013, but now
> only 47 percent say they support it today.
>
> That makes white evangelicals the only religious group without a
> majority who support a pathway to citizenship, a difference that
> widens when limited to those who attend religious services weekly or
> more (58% to 45%).

https://www.christianitytoday.com/news/2022/february/evangelical-immigration-pathway-to-citizenship-shift-prri.html

Why does a majority of White Evangelicals not support a pathway to citizenship for undocumented migrants? The article says that a majority of that group used to support a pathway to citizenship in 2013, but it is no longer the case, and now a majority is against it. What happened since then and why are they no longer supporting it?

Comment: The historical logic for US Evangelicals was sectarian balance-of-power, as North American migrants tend to be Catholic. But as the article makes clear, the downtrend is nearly uniform. And in particular, Catholic support has also fallen. This ofc implies there must be another reason. The most obvious candidate IMO would be the broadening wave of economic nationalism, in which anti-immigrant sentiment is reformulated by the right into a "kitchen table" issue, via the connection between immigration and supply/demand in the labor market.

Comment: So support went from slim majority over 50% to even slimmer minority under 50%. That's called "mixed" results, and likely just polling error and the religious ideology is likely unrelated to the issue. Trying to dig for an explanation is likely trying to model noise (over fitting) when there was a weak correlation to begin with.

Comment: @uberhaxed - the Q focuses on white evangelicals, who showed a -9% swing. In contrast to a -1% swing in US adults overall

Comment: 80% of such Evangelicals voted Trump in 2016.  75% in 2020.  They've become intertwined with MAGA.  Causality is hard to prove tho.  https://www.reuters.com/world/us/trump-keeps-edge-among-evangelicals-there-is-an-opening-challengers-2023-04-20/ https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2021/08/30/most-white-americans-who-regularly-attend-worship-services-voted-for-trump-in-2020/

Comment: Why are you closing your own questions?

Comment: @PeteW yes, when sampling a small number of people, percentages close to 50% are basically just noise. Qualifying 3% over half as "most", should have been a flashing light.

Comment: There is no such thing that "right to live in the USA" and there is no such thing that "right to live in a state with a higher life standards as your current one". Note, being poor is actually a gift, but most of us is not enough high level of holiness to value it. The evangelicals see it differently, they believe that that living well is the gift of the God.